# Top margin alignment in a row in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have  a row in bootstrap with a label,textbox and button.

But the top edges of the label and text box are not getting aligned. Is there any way in bootstrap to fix this.

Code:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">

                <h4><span class="label classone control-label">Your Purchased items</span></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-5">

                <input type="search"
                       class="col-md-12 form-control"
                       placeholder="Enter item code or item name" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <input type="button"
                       class="form-control btn btn-default btn-xs searchButton"
                       value="Search" />
            </div>

</div>
```

**Fiddle Link:**
http://jsfiddle.net/ponsakthi/eTJ7j/embedded/result/

Answer (score 1):

You could add the below CSS:

```
h4 {
line-height:0.2em; 
margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
```

}

Note that this would affect all elements using h4, though does align with the other elements on the page.

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily done using :
    h4 { display:inline; }